# how to set caption for calculated measure in MDX

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

i have a MDX query in Mondrian like below

```
with member [Measures].[a] as '([Measures].[LCount] * 2)'
 member [Measures].[b] as '([Measures].[a] * 3)'
select {[Rate].[Rate].Members} ON COLUMNS,
{[Measures].[a], [Measures].[b]} ON ROWS
from [c];
```

and i want to set caption for my calculated measures that is different with their uniqeName
what should i do?

NOTICE :

```
with member [Measures].[a] as '([Measures].[LCount] * 2)',
CAPTION = "my measure"
```

doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a statement similar to

```
with member [Measures].[a] as '([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] * 2)', Caption = 'my measure'
     member [Measures].[b] as '([Measures].[a] * 3)'
select {[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].members} ON COLUMNS,
       {[Measures].[a], [Measures].[b]} ON ROWS
from [Adventure Works];
```

and it worked without problems. Note: I used *single quotes* for the caption text.

Just a remark unrelated to this: You can omit the quotes around the member definition if you do not need compatibility with Analysis Services in the 2000 version. This sometimes (but not in this case) gives you better syntax error messages.

Comment: @FrankPI but it doesn't work for me!! :(  do you know whats the problem

Comment: do you have 'my measure' as your title?

Comment: @sami I edited my answer, showing you the exact query that I ran successfully on the Microsoft Adventure Works cube. **Please note the single quotes around the caption name.** What is the error message that you get?

Comment: I have no errors but i don't have 'my measures' as title of my calculated measure 'a' ... it always shows 'a' as the title :(

Comment: @sami If you are writing the Java code yourself, can you not just use the caption property of the measure for the display?

Comment: no because i used the result in table and our table display title on base of MDX result ( it written before)

Comment: @sami The MDX result should contain the unique name and the caption of every member on every axis. So it should be there, you just have to know how to access it.